# Adding two Text Fields in a ViewController and displaying it in another ViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uitextfield

I'm using a `NavigationViewController` and 2 View Controllers (named `ViewController` and `ResultViewController`), to make a simple app, that will sum 2 textFields in the first ViewController and display the result in a label, in the `ResultViewController`. I'm using a push segue to connect the VCs, but I can't create a variable that receives the sum from the textFields. The error says: "property sum not found on object of type 'ViewController' ". I also tried to create the sum variable inside the `prepareForSegue` method, without success...

Below, my first `ViewController.m` code snippet:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
 {  
 }

- (IBAction)addButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {

ResultViewController *tempView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ResultViewController"];

double sum = [_fieldOne.text doubleValue] + [_fieldTwo.text doubleValue];

tempView.answer = self.sum.text; //here appears the error I mentioned

[self presentViewController:tempView animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

The `ResultViewController.m` snippet:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
self.displaySum.text = self.answer;
}
```

Any help will be really appreciated! Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sum is a local variable. You want

```
tempView.answer = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",sum];
```